# Facebook Custom Stories not appearing in activity feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-stream-story, custom-stories

I'm using Facebook's JavaScript SDK to create a custom story.

```
FB.login(function() {
            FB.api(
                'me/' + fb_app_namespace + ':review_a_book',
                'post',
                {
                    book: "http://samples.ogp.me/199815506812566"
                },
                function(response) {
                    // handle the response
                    if (!response) {
                        alert('Error occurred.');
                    } else if (response.error) {
                        $('#result').text('Error: ' + response.error.message);
                    } else {
                        $('#result').html('<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/' +
                        response.id + '\">' +
                        'Story created.  ID is ' +
                        response.id + '</a>');
                    }
                }
            );
}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

The Custom Story 'Review A Book' is setup in the App Dashboard and the JS fires correctly without error. The problem comes in when I try to view the Activity in my Activity Log. It just isn't there. Also the link generated presents me with a page that simple says 'This content is currently unavailable'.

The Application is Public, and at the very least should work with me as an Admin or Developer.

Any help would be appreciated.